# In SwiftUI, How to access the view that is calling onDisappear() modifier in the closure of it?

Tags: swiftui

I think it is quite a simple logic but can't find a solution anywhere. Basically, I just want to access the view that is calling onDisappear() modifier in the closure of the modifier onDisappear.

```
struct HostView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EditView()
    .onDisappear {
      //I want to access the EditView in here and get property1
    }
  }
}
```

```
struct EditView: View {
  @State var property1: Int?
}
```

I found a solution that uses a global class that holds static variables. Like this

```
class AClass {
  static var tempVar: Int?
}
```

Then, use that like this.

```
struct HostView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EditView()
    .onDisappear {
      //I want to access the EditView in here and get property1
      let a = AClass.tempVar
    }
  }
}
```

```
struct EditView: View {
  @State var property1: Int?
  
  //call updateTempVar() somewhere here

  func updateTempVar() {
    AClass.tempVar = property1
  }
}
```

However, I don't think this is the right solution. I think there should be something else much easier...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What do you try to achieve actually? Because what you do is not SwfitUI like, moreover it has not much sense because onDisappear is called *after* view disappeared, so it is absent, so what to update.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you. I didn't know it is called after the view disappeared. Then, Swift has viewWillDisappear(), which you can call inside the view before it disappears, is there any way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `HostView` is a simple struct you can just hold the `EditView` as a `var` inside your `HostView` like this:

```
struct HostView: View {
    var editView = EditView() 
    var body: some View {
    editView
        .onDisappear {
            print(editView.property1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me because, in my case,  I have to initialize the EditView in the body after the HostView initialized already.